# How did my book know that $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ was unacceptable for this ellipse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, conic-sections

**Question:**

Find the equation of the ellipse, coordinates of whose foci are $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ and the length of whose latera recta is $3$.

**My book's attempt:**

$$2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=2$$

$$b^2=a^2-1\tag{1}$$

Now,

$$\frac{2b^2}{a}=3$$

$$\frac{2(a^2-1)}{a}=3$$

$$a=2,-\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$

---

Now immediately after line $(2)$, my book asserted that $-\frac{1}{2}$ isn't an acceptable value of $a$, but how did my book know this just by looking at it? I only understood that $-\frac{1}{2}$ wasn't acceptable by inputting it in $(1)$: we get $b^2=-\frac{3}{4}$, which is impossible.

So, how did my book know that $a\neq-\frac{1}{2}$ just by looking at it?

Comment: By the exact logic you stated.  You had to take a moment to verify why the statement was correct; the author has done the same and given you the courtesy of figuring out the reason for yourself.

Comment: Constant $a$ is positive by definition, hence...

Comment: Just simple look on $b^2=a^2-1 \ge 0 \implies a^2 \ge1$.